# How to debug a java port/socket/connection from external application (remotely)?

Tags: java, networking, jmx, remote-debugging, jpda

I use jpda to debug a java application remotely, by tracing its function calls.

What if I want to trace the java connection activity (database connection, or REST call to 3rd party service)?

Comment: I'd use a packet sniffer myself.  Something like tcpdump under Unix/MacOS.  I'm sure there are Windows packages which do the same.

Comment: You could also use Wireshark on linux and macos.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, some java library like jpda.

Comment: I found Jpcap and jnetpcap. They seems very promising.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623681/jnetpcap-vs-jpcap][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623681/jnetpcap-vs-jpcap