# Java PCAP file parser library

Tags: java, pcap

I'm looking for a fast way to parse PCAP file packets.

I'm currently using [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/?q=examples/offline) like so:

```
Pcap pcap = Pcap.openOffline(file, errbuf);
pcap.loop(10, jpacketHandler, "jNetPcap rocks!");
```

But it is pretty slow, is there any other good Java libraries that can parse PCAP files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just stumbled upon pcap parsing task in Java and found a [pcap parser in Kaitai Struct](http://formats.kaitai.io/pcap/java.html). Surprisingly, it turns out to be blazing fast — probably because it's not a wrapper over C pcap library, but just a raw parser instead. My average results (on the same box, of course) are as following:

- jpcap - 10,301 pps
- jnetpcap - 15,148 pps
- pcap.ksy in Kaitai Struct - 121,176 pps

So, if you don't need *capturing*, I wholeheartedly recommend trying out Kaitai Struct parser.

Answer (score 4):

**jNetPcap** is the most stable and well written wrapper. Its better than JPcap see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3623681/2115983) for comparison details. And i don't have a comparison details for [pcap4j](http://www.pcap4j.org/) to evaluate.