# Listening to all the data on a certain port

Tags: java, sockets

My task is to implement an application that will accept all the information that comes to a certain port. It should work like Wireshark.

This code should listen to everything that comes to port 46122.
In Wireshark,  I see that some information comes to this port. But my program does not see anything.

```
   ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(46122);
   Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: This will only record the data sent over a TCP connection. It won't record the TCP/IP headers, or anything sent with a different protocol. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful That's the problem. I will not see any packages until no one client is connected to this server, am I understood right? But how does Wireshark do it?

Comment: @erickson I see a lot of data that received on this port in Wireshark. But my program does'nt. How to see the data? Appreciate very much

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3623681/3474

Comment: Your program doesn't *do* anything except listen and accept one socket. If you want to see data you have to *read* it. Your assignment should be returned as infeasible in Java and also beyond your present skills.

Comment: @EJP Many thanks, but it's up to me. It would be more useful to show me any ideas for solving this problem using jNetPcap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to record entire TCP packets with Java, you'll need a third-party library that has a "native" component. The core Java libraries cannot do this. Library recommendations are off-topic, "pcap" and "java" might be helpful search keywords.

Comment: Upvoted, +1. Stll that'd be a poor choice to design such application using java. I'd not suggest anyone to use Java for developing such a tool, unless it is the last option.

Comment: May be you can recommend any library? Without links, only name

Comment: And explain please what means "native" component?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Yes, you are right, but this is my task. I have no choice :(

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Why?

Comment: @erickson - Because, the libraries you mentioned are also incomplete to achieve the state as perfect as that of Wireshark. I'd bet still on C for developing such tools which deal with layer-2 and layer-3 Internet stack. But, I agree that the simpler model can be built using Java.

Comment: @Cyryl I commented on your post with a link to another question where some libraries are mentioned. (I also voted to close it.) That's a good place to start. A native component is a library that is written in C or C++, and linked to Java code. This can make your Java code less portable, since you'll need to have that C or C++ compiled for each platform you want to run on.